# Overriding panel.grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code first drops the X-axis text, and then adds it back in with a red color:

```
p_text <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = hp, y = disp) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
p_text + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "red"))
```

Similarly, one would expect this code to do the same thing for the grid lines:

```
p_grid <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = hp, y = disp) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
p_grid + theme(panel.grid = element_line(colour = "red"))
```

However, it only appears to add them back with default colors. Why this strange behavior, and is there a way to add the panel grid lines back in? (My actual example involves overriding various pre-set themes, so just setting the grid lines right away is not an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `theme_grey` you can see that `panel.grid.minor` and `panel.grid.major` are both specified. When you specify `panel.grid` to a specific color, the minor and major grid lines would inherit this if a color wasn't specified for them. But there is.

This works as expected:

```
p_grid <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = hp, y = disp) + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
p_grid + theme(panel.grid = element_line(colour = "blue"), #needed to overwrite element_blank
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "red"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "red"))
```

and this too:

```
p_grid + theme(panel.grid = element_line(colour = "red"), 
               panel.grid.major = NULL,
               panel.grid.minor = NULL)
```